# Windows 8 JavaScript App Development: Draw on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I'm working on a Windows 8 app in JavaScript. I've been taking advantage of the code Samples in the Windows 8 Dev Center but I'm stuck. I want to add a div to my HTML code such as: `<div id="drawArea"></div>` and use JavaScript so that you can draw in this area with the mouse or your finger (if using a touchscreen) like in MS Paint.

There's no code samples for this in the Dev Center in JavaScript. I would think there would be since Windows 8 is designed for touch screens. I tried some of the many HTML5/JavaScript canvas drawing tutorials from a quick Google search but all are jerky when compiled as a Windows 8 JavaScript app in Visual Studio.

Any suggestions would be appreciated?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of samples that show what you're asking (but they're named after "Ink", not touch, so they're easier to miss):

- [Input: Ink sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Ink-App-sample-61abaec3)
- [Input: Simplified Ink sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Input-simplified-ink-sample-11614bbf)

Both show a general drawing experience, using `<canvas>` for the drawing surface, `MSPointer` to get input events, and [`Windows.UI.Input.Inking`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.inking) / [`InkManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.inking.inkmanager.aspx) to process (capture, save/load, copy, hit test) strokes.

However, the first sample goes into more detail with touch and other features, but of course has more code to digest.

There's also a quickstart tutorial that shows mouse/pen/touch with ink and `<canvas>` for display:

- [Quickstart: Capturing ink data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh465086.aspx)